# Tesla's "REST" API, and honk_horn end-point

Tags: web-services, rest, http

```
GET /vehicles/{id}/command/honk_horn
```

As seen in this post:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7961944

There is a debate about what verb should be used for the `honk_horn` resource. Answers include:

- GET, because you're not changing the resource state
- POST and not PUT because honking twice is not idempotent
- PUT, because honking twice might be considered idempotent :S

Perhaps the root of the problem here is that `honk_horn` is really an action and not a resource, and so in this particular case how should one define as API to issue a command while remaining RESTful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps the root of the problem here is that honk_horn is really an action and not a resource

Yes, I would say so, that's the core of the problem. A resource oriented and hypermedia based approach could look like this (using Mason https://github.com/JornWildt/Mason to describe actions):

```
GET /vehicles/12345/horn  => return status of horn (a resource in itself)

{
  volume: 5,
  numberOfHonks: 1025,
  @actions:
  {
    "honk":
    {
      type: "void",
      href: "/vehicles/12345/horn/honks",
      method: "POST",
      title: "POST here to honk horn once"
    }
  }
}


GET /vehicles/12345/horn/honks   => return previous honks (a resource in itself)

{
  numberOfHonks: 1025,
  honks:
  [
    { date: "2010-12-24T10:24:12" },
    { date: "2010-12-24T10:24:14" },
    { date: "2010-12-24T10:24:20" },
    ... 1022 other honks (or perhaps only latest top 100 honks)
  ]
}

POST /vehicles/12345/horn/honks  => Add one honk (empty payload - or maybe even include volume and pitch ...)
```

Fun exercise :-)

Comment: This seems to be best way even though I don't think Tesla wants a honk to change the state of the server. I guess there is no RESTful approach to do that and would need to take a hybrid REST/RPC approach.